# SEO Boost on launch?

Tags: seo, google

Will Google give you a SEO launch on your start, so that you can rank upper or in the first 10-20 on the very same day you get indexed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because it doesn't make sense. If this was true, then people would just create new domains for $2, rank them for a day for some profitable keywords and get $200 back. Actually, a new site has a high probability of being a spam site, so it should have to prove its legitimacy first.

Comment: Indeed, for new sites on new domains there is also the possibility of the "Google Sandbox", where the site has to prove itself for a few weeks or months before it's allowed into the higher positions...

Answer (score 10):

No.

**update**

This is because it in no way indicates a page's or site's quality. Being new doesn't mean the site is good. If the content is high quality Google's algorithm will naturally account for it as the site will accumulate quality links over time. So there is no need for an arbitrary bonus. Even a temporary one.

Answer (score 3):

As John Conde said, you'll not get any boost. Anyway, if the contents have been created within a date very close to the current date, they'll get a better ranking if the user will use the date range filters in the Google advanced search.

Comment: or if Google determines that the Query Deserves Freshness and automatically puts recent content at the top.

Comment: @joshuahedlund exactly. Indeed Matt Cutts asserted that Google S.E. will give more relevance to the freshness ones.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're wanting to rank for. You can probably rank very quickly for an obscure term that matches or closely matches your domain name. For example, if you had herrkKaleunblog.com you could probably rank #1 right away for "Herr Kaleun Blog". But, there's no way you would come in the top 1000 for something competitive like "credit cards" or "lose weight" unless you were getting direct links from the top sites for that keyword (even then it would be iffy).

Comment: well i'm actually ranking for a cargo companies directory witch is something similar to "cargo-company.com" where people search for the terms "cargo company new york" or similar.

Well if there is not any boost, should i think that my SEO/ranking is good?